# Insert ^{ before a superscripted word

Tags: vba, ms-word

If there is any subscripted character (say x) in the text selected in my word doc, I am trying to convert it to _{x} using following code in vba macro. Similarly, converting superscripts to ^{x}. It is replacing the subscripts properly, but unable to insert ^ in case of superscripts.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve it?

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Font.Superscript = True
    .Replacement.Text = "^{^&}"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Font.Subscript = True
    .Replacement.Text = "_{^&}"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

I am also trying to achieve it with following code. It is identifying the character that is subscripted or super scripted, and replacing it with _{ or ^{, rather than inserting those before the character.

```
Sub ChangeToSuperScript()
Dim X As Long
Dim Position As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim scr As Boolean

For Each c In Range("K1:L1") 'range of cells
    i = 1
    superSc = False
    subSc = False
    
    Do While i <= Len(c.Formula)
        Select Case True
            Case (c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript = True) And (superSc = False)

                c.Characters(i, 3).Insert ("^{" & c.Characters(i, 1).Text)
                
                i = i + 2
                superSc = True
            Case (c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Subscript = True) And (subSc = False)
                c.Characters(i, 1).Insert ("_{" & c.Characters(i, 1).Text)
                i = i + 2
                subSc = True
            Case (c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript = False) And (superSc = True)
                c.Characters(i + 1, 1).Insert ("}" & c.Characters(i + 1, 1).Text)
                i = i + 1
                superSc = False
            Case (c.Characters(i, 1).Font.Subscript = False) And (subSc = True)
                c.Characters(i + 1, 1).Insert ("}" & c.Characters(i + 1, 1).Text)
                i = i + 1
                subSc = False
        End Select
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like Word VBA?

Comment: I edited the post, and added excel vba that I tried, but it is replacing the existing character x, rather than inserting a ^{ before it.

Comment: Excel Replace doesn't have that capability.

Comment: ok, then I will do it with word macro, and the 1st macro in my question, is working for subscripts, but for superscripts, it is giving error ^{ is not a valid special character for replacement with box. Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an update on the word macro:

It was giving error with ^ as it is used as escape code in word's find/replace functionality. I have given ^^ to indicate it is not an escape code, and it worked fine.

final code:

```
With Selection.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 .Font.Superscript = True
 .Replacement.Text = "^^{^&}"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 .Font.Subscript = True
 .Replacement.Text = "_{^&}"
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```